# Why is my event listener written in Google Closure not working?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-library

I have a function in my Google Closure code with an event listener that aims to append HTML generated by a soy template to the body when the body loads:

```
/**
 * Constructs the home page.
 */
AppLoader.prototype.constructHomePage = function() {
  goog.events.listen(document.body, 'onload', function() {
      document.body.innerHTML = templates.home.main();});
}

(new AppLoader()).constructHomePage();
```

However, it does not work. Chrome Console also offers no errors. What I have tried is the below code, which uses the addEventListener function native to javascript.

```
... class instantiation
/**
 * Constructs the home page.
 */
AppLoader.prototype.constructHomePage = function() {
  document.body.innerHTML = templates.home.main();
}

document.body.addEventListener('load', function() {
  (new AppLoader()).constructHomePage();
}, false);
```

This latter method works, but does not use Closure at all, so I don't feel that it is reliable. Why is my event listener written in Google Closure not working?

Answer (score 0):

you should stop the browser events.

event.stopPropagation();

Answer (score 0):

You should attach it to the window object.

```
goog.events.listenOnce(
  window
, goog.events.EventType.LOAD
, function(){
    window.alert( 'Ready for ADVANCED_COMPILATION!' );
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Closure if you listen for a "load" event on the 'window' object instead of the document body.

Try this:
`goog.events.listen(window, "load", function(){//code })`

P.S., I'm sorry that my answer is 8 years late